# dd failed on ms partition

Tags: gparted, rsync, dd

I tried to dd an MS partition. This usually works. Gparted found problems on the disk, so, i chkdsk /R /F a couple of times. Windows Disk management saw no errors. Gparted is more sensitive. It seemed to be in a Windows.old directory. Defrag couldn't pull it out. It felt as if a sneak attack by Windows 10 on an unsuspecting Win 7 system stuck and burned a pit. That was why it came down to me to fix. All I could do for the client was a clean install from a 7 iso.

- Is there an option in dd to circumvent a "pit"?
- Would rsync have been a better option?

She got the Windows version of an image for a fall back. Sometimes I just get tired and have to deliver. She did not want windows 10. At least, I grabbed her work so she could continue on an old XP spare box.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to dd, you might try using [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) which will try multiple times to read bad sectors.  The ddrescue program is included on many GNU/Linux live images, such as [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).